# Getting Values from MultiDimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

My Array shown as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [amount_id] => 1
        [enquiry_id] => 1
        [project_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [amount_id] => 4
        [enquiry_id] => 4
        [project_id] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [amount_id] => 5
        [enquiry_id] => 5
        [project_id] => 5
    )

)
```

This Array can be increase. How can i get value of each 'amount_id' from this array? What function should i use? Can for each function will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $data) {
  $output[] = $data['amount_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one-liner [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to print those..

```
array_walk($arr,function($v){ echo $v['amount_id']."<br>";});
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/138132)

Comment: This will print all elements, and not a specific one. I think the question is "each" element

Answer (score 1):

Do like this in `array_map` or Use [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for The version PHP 5.5 or greater

```
 $outputarr= array_map(function($item){ return $item['amount_id'];},$yourarr);
 print_r($outputarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this is accessing the specific array - easier to debug later on and better speed:

```
$num=count($your_array);
for($i="0"; $i<$num; $i++)
    {
    echo $your_array[$i]['amount_id'];
    }
```

you could loop until $i < count($your_array) but it means that the count will run in every loop, for high performance sites I wouldn't do it.

you could access a specific element in a 2D array by $your_array[$the_index]['amount_id']  or other index.